# Add Loading Text to Colorbox Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

For the Colorbox jQuery plugin ([found here](http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)):

I know there is a loading graphic for colorbox (set as the background of the #LoadingGraphic div), but how can I get text to appear below the loading graphic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be the most ideal but it looks like it works. **Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JBVru/1/)**

When you initialize the Colorbox plugin, the loadingdiv will be created but hidden. You could append a div inside of it and give it some styles.

```
$(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1'});
$("#cboxLoadingOverlay").append("<div class='loading-text'>My Loading Text</div>")
```

CSS

```
.loading-text{margin-top:50px; font-weight:bold; font-family:arial; font-size:20px}
```